# How to generate unique ids for html divs while looping in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying to do is create a "save", "edit", and "hide: button for my website which applies to specific posts and comments, exactly like these buttons on Reddit. For now I am trying to self teach jQuery AJAX and attempting to figure out how to submit data to the database without having to reload the whole page. What I am attempting to do here is save a string by submitting it to a table called "Saved" when I click on "save", and edit, and hide the specific comment. However, the div id is static. I want to be able to make it dynamic when run through the loop so I can call the id selector in jQuery to complete the ajax functions for the specific comment. However, I cannot put php code into jQuery so calling the specific php $id variable is out of the question.

**HTML and PHP5**

```
<div id="main">
    <?php
        $comments = array("Message 1 is the first!", "Message 2 comes in second!", "This is the third message!");    

        for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
            $id = $i;
            $comment = $comments[$i - 1];
            displayMsg($id, $comment);
        }
    ?>
    <form action="ajaxexample.php" method="post" style="display: none" id="1234">
        <input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="<?php echo $comment; ?>">
    </form> 
</div>
    </form>
```

**PHP function**

// Replace message1 with $id

```
function displayMsg($id, $comment){
    echo "<div id=\"message\" . $id ." style=\"border: solid 1px; width: 20%;\">";
    echo "<div id=\"pmessage\"><p>$comment</p></div>";
    echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"Save\" style=\"color: blue;\">Save</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"Edit\" style=\"color: blue;\">Edit</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"Hide\" style=\"color: blue;\">Hide</a>";     
    echo "</div>";  
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.Save').click(function () {

    });
    $('a.Hide').click(function () {
        $("#message" + $id).hide();
        $("#message"  + $id).fadeIn(2000);
    });
    $('a.Edit').click(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "Edit") {
            $("#pmessage").css("color", "red");
            $("a.Edit").text("Unedit");
        } else {
            $("#pmessage").css("color", "black");
            $("a.Edit").text("Edit");
        }
    });

    $('a.Save').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#1234").submit();
    });

    $("#1234").submit(function(e) {
        $("a.Save").text("Saving...");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'ajaxexample.php',
               data: $("#1234").serialize(),
               success: function(data)
               {
                $("a.Save").text("Unsave");
               }
             });
    });
});
```

Comment: You cannot have *any* duplicate id's. Use classes and then use jQuery's ability to traverse the DOM to perform the actions you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the div parent instead :

```
$('a.Hide').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).parent().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

OR, you can add the attribute `rel` to your `<a>` like following :

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"Edit\" rel=\"" . $id ."\" style=\"color: blue;\">Edit</a>";
echo "<a href=\"#\" class=\"Hide\" rel=\"" . $id ."\" style=\"color: blue;\">Hide</a>";
```

And then :

```
$('a.Hide').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('#message' + id).hide();
    $('#message' + id).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

For the edit button, change `id="pmessage"` to `class="pmessage"`, the ID must be unique :

```
$('a.Edit').click(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "Edit") {
        $(this).parent().find('.pmessage').css("color", "red");
        $(this).text("Unedit"); // <-- HERE, use $(this) instead
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find('.pmessage').css("color", "black");
        $(this).text("Edit"); // <-- HERE, use $(this) instead
    }
});
```

About the save part :

```
$('a.Save').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).parent().find('form'),
        $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
           type: $form.attr('method'),
           url: $form.attr('action'),
           data: $form.serialize(),
           beforeSend : function(){
               $this.text("Saving...");
           },
           success: function(data)
           {
              $this.text("Saved");
           },
           error: function(){
              $this.text("Unsaved");
           }
         });
});
/*
$("#1234").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
           type: $this.attr('method'),
           url: $this.attr('action'),
           data: $this.serialize(),
           beforeSend : function(){
               $("a.Save").text("Saving...");
           },
           success: function(data)
           {
              $("a.Save").text("Saved");
           },
           error: function(){
              $("a.Save").text("Unsaved");
           }
         });
});
*/
```

Create one form for each comment :

```
function displayMsg($id, $comment){
    echo '<div id="message' . $id .'" style="border: solid 1px; width: 20%;">';
    echo '<div class="pmessage">'.$comment.'</div>';
    echo '<a href="#" rel="'.$id.'"  class="Save" style="color: blue;">Save</a>';
    echo '<a href="#" rel="'.$id.'" class="Edit" style="color: blue;">Edit</a>';
    echo '<a href="#" rel="'.$id.'" class="Hide" style="color: blue;">Hide</a>';
    echo '<form method="POST" action="mypage.php" style="display:none">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="message" value="'.$comment.'">';
    echo '</form>'
    echo '</div>';
}
```

NB : You need to change the `a.save` click statement.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! How do I only change the <a> tags in their respective divs after I click on them? When I press edit, all of the edit <a> tags change to unedit. Is there anyway I could just change the one I click?

Comment: @The_Perfect_Username you should use `$(this)` instead of global selector, check my updated answer

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, thanks. Do you know how to do the "save" part? Trying to work out the form and input along with the jQuery really has me stumped.

Comment: Ok, what's the problem with the save part ?

Comment: Well since I am looping the comments div the value of the hidden input will only store the very last element in the array after the loop has completed. I want to be able to save the comment in the specific div after I click on the save button in that div.

Comment: Check the update, I'm assuming you have `a.save` button for each comment

Comment: Yes I do. The code doesn't really work. Nothing is being submitted to the database now. Could you look at the html input as well to see what should be in the value attribute?

Comment: did you changed `id="pmessage"` to `class="pmessage"` ?

Comment: I think it will be better if you create one form for each comment

Comment: Ah that was the issue. Thanks for that!

Comment: Create a form for each comment? How would I go about doing that? That makes sense and would be easier for bypassing complicated jQuery code, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id to  element for example

```
 echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"".$id."\" class=\"Save\" style=\"color: blue;\">Save</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"".$id."\"  class=\"Edit\" style=\"color: blue;\">Edit</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"#\" id=\"".$id."\"  class=\"Hide\" style=\"color: blue;\">Hide</a>";
```

then

```
$('a.Save').click(function () {

var id=$(this).attr('id');

    });
```

or use function  onclick and in javascript manage them separately

```
 echo "<div style=\"color: blue;\" onclick=\"save($id)\">Save</div>";
```

...

Comment: Could you expand on the jQuery with the save function? I'm finding it hard to solve. I can only save the very last comment in the loop.

Comment: use the function save of the answer before passing id or rel like explained